# NSUserDefaults can not save and delete

Tags: swift, xcode, settings

I've just got a problem. I used NSUserDefaults to store user settings using this way:

```
//Crete obj
let settings = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

//Saving the data
settings.setObject("myValue", forKey: "number")
settings.synchronize()

//Getting the data
if let val = settings.objectForKey("number") as? String {
   print("you have value in storage")
}

//Delete the data
settings.removeObjectForKey("number")
```

And it was working fine... Until now. Now I cant save, delete or edit data from the storage. Every methods returns `true` but values in NSUserDefaults does not changing. It always retured one value that I saved this morning. I reverted last commit, but it did not help me. I reinstalled the app on emulator but it did not helped too. It always returned the same value.

What have i to do?

Comment: Is this behavior specific to the simulator? If so, I think there's a known bug about this. You can try using "Reset Content and Settings..." in the Simulator's Simulator menu.

Comment: @Norman tnx, it helped!